# Is it possible to format date in command line to specific format?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

Am trying to format date in cmd windows but it is not coming out nicely.

`echo %date% +"%d-%B-%Y"`. How should I go about it?

Comment: User PowerShell in CMD: `powershell.exe get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the wmic command which can return the local date/time in a locale-independent manner.

---

```
@echo off
Title wmic command which can return the local date/time in a locale-independent manner
@for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%
echo Today : %today%
set "year=%MyDate:~2,2%"
set "month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
set "day=%MyDate:~6,2%"
echo %day%-%month%-%year%
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

I belive this is what you want:

```
set year=%date:~10,4%
set month=%date:~4,2%
set day=%date:~7,2%
set dateformatted=%month%-%day%-%year%
echo %dateformatted%
```

Answer from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473267/16108971)
Have fun!

Comment: This prints `9--1--021` on my pc. (Note that `%date%` is culture specific)

Comment: Wouldn't chopping up `wmic os get LocalDateTime` be a better (locale independent) solution?

Comment: @Richard Absolutely. That link contains several answers (of which `%date%` is the worst, IMO), including wmic.

Comment: @Berend Hah, serves me right for not looking at the contents of the link! The biggest issue I can see is the requirement for `%B` which will require matching a number to the full name of the month.

Comment: Idk why but wmic gives some whacky numbers instead of a date on my computer. There is the answer's URL if it didn't work for you guys. I guess it changes from area to area.

Comment: @TheCodeExpert Odd, mine gives `20211119131755.595000+000` which looks to be `yyyymmddhhmmss`. I have no idea what is after the `.` - I'm guessing sub-seconds but it's hard to tell because it takes a second for Windows to return the value.

Comment: @Richard I'm getting your result when I run wmic. I guess it really depends on something